# Получить все даты в формате ММ ГГГГ между двумя датами

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть таблица, столбец с начальной датой и столбец с конечной датой, оба столбца в формате месяц.год (09.2022), нужно в третий столбец "период" записать все даты между этими двумя (начальной и конечной) соответственно в формате месяц.год.
У меня именно с месяцем не получается сделать.

Вот файл. [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1miX0u1q9Frb4FgScS4_JubXf9ROogUtZ/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=106434889534507496883&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Пыталась сделать что-то аналогичное по дням, вроде получилось, но конечный формат не получается перевести в день месяц год.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'sdate':['22-03-2019', '30-03-2019'], 'edate':['07-04-2019', '08-04-2019']})

#создание столбца days
df1.loc[:, "days"] = df1.apply(
    
    lambda x: list(
        pd.date_range(
            x.sdate, 
            x.edate
        ).date
    ),
    axis = 1
    
)
# вывод объекта DataFrame
df1

sdate   edate   days
0   22-03-2019  07-04-2019  [2019-03-22, 2019-03-23, 2019-03-24, 2019-03-2...
1   30-03-2019  08-04-2019  [2019-03-30, 2019-03-31, 2019-04-01, 2019-04-0..
```

Полученный столбец с датами не могу перевести в формат хотя бы 22-03-2019.

Answer (score 2):

Вам не надо переводить полученный столбец в другой формат - он у вас как раз в формате datetime pandas. у вас исходные столбцы в неверном формате (в виде строк). если вы сделаете так, то все сами поймете:

```
df["нач дат"] = pd.to_datetime(df["нач дат"], format="%m.%Y")
df["кон дат"] = pd.to_datetime(df["кон дат"], format="%m.%Y")
df["период"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x["нач дат"], x["кон дат"], freq="MS").date, axis=1)
```

```
      нач дат    кон дат                                             период
0  2019-07-01 2021-05-01  [2019-07-01, 2019-08-01, 2019-09-01, 2019-10-0...
1  2021-09-01 2021-12-01   [2021-09-01, 2021-10-01, 2021-11-01, 2021-12-01]
2  2019-01-01 2021-04-01  [2019-01-01, 2019-02-01, 2019-03-01, 2019-04-0...
3  2019-01-01 2022-01-01  [2019-01-01, 2019-02-01, 2019-03-01, 2019-04-0...
4  2019-01-01 2020-06-01  [2019-01-01, 2019-02-01, 2019-03-01, 2019-04-0...
5  2019-01-01 2022-06-01  [2019-01-01, 2019-02-01, 2019-03-01, 2019-04-0...
6  2019-01-01 2022-06-01  [2019-01-01, 2019-02-01, 2019-03-01, 2019-04-0...

и т. д.
```

как видите, я добавил частоту в метод `to_datetime` - тогда у вас в списке будет только по одному объекту за каждый месяц.

Для отображения периода именно в строковом формате "месяц-год", можно еще добавить:

```
df["период"] = df["период"].apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: f"{y[0]}-{y[1]}", zip(x.month, x.year))))
```

получим:

```
      нач дат    кон дат                                             период
0  2019-07-01 2021-05-01  [7-2019, 8-2019, 9-2019, 10-2019, 11-2019, 12-...
1  2021-09-01 2021-12-01                [9-2021, 10-2021, 11-2021, 12-2021]
2  2019-01-01 2021-04-01  [1-2019, 2-2019, 3-2019, 4-2019, 5-2019, 6-201...
3  2019-01-01 2022-01-01  [1-2019, 2-2019, 3-2019, 4-2019, 5-2019, 6-201...
4  2019-01-01 2020-06-01  [1-2019, 2-2019, 3-2019, 4-2019, 5-2019, 6-201...
5  2019-01-01 2022-06-01  [1-2019, 2-2019, 3-2019, 4-2019, 5-2019, 6-201...
6  2019-01-01 2022-06-01  [1-2019, 2-2019, 3-2019, 4-2019, 5-2019, 6-201...
7  2019-01-01 2021-10-01  [1-2019, 2-2019, 3-2019, 4-2019, 5-2019, 6-201...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, результат получился как мне нужно, именно по месяцам. Но, формат не тот, формат результата нужен  месяц год.   Пробовала так: print((datetime(df1['период'])).strftime("%m/%Y"))  - ошибку даёт TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, результат получился тот что надо.))